# Docker install causes host machine to be unreachable

Tags: docker

I am installing the latest version of docker on a ubuntu 16.04 vmware. After install I cant ssh to the box.
Is docker making some network changes that cause this?
Never had this issue before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our local workstation network is: 172.18.0.0/24

The docker0 interface is 172.18.0.0/16

netstat -rn had route for 172.18.0.0 -> docker0

We changed the docker0 interface subnet using : https://support.zenoss.com/hc/en-us/articles/203582809-How-to-Change-the-Default-Docker-Subnet

Reloaded docker and started containers.

Working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your UFW rules somehow changed from the install.

```
$ sudo ufw status numbered
```

and if SSH is still running on the host machine.